# Collections Jpa Spring Data return No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: jpa, collections, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I'm using jpa and I have the entity below:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "rid"))
private Collection<UserRole> roles;
```

and this is my specification filter

```
if (!filter.getRoles().isEmpty()) {

        System.out.println("Append roles");
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("roles"), filter.getRoles()));
    }
```

what i wanted to do is to query based of role given in the filter. i have collection of roles in user profile entity and my search is on user profile entity.

this is what spring display my error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

im confused a bit when it comes to collections query.

Comment: You havent posted the rest of the query execution code, like where you have DEFINED a parameter in your query, and where you set the value of that parameter. Also you cannot use a MULTI-VALUED field in an equality filter!

Answer (score 0):

here is the update for answer that ive been searching around. maybe it will help others rather than give negative points for a valid question.

```
   if (filter.getRoles() != null) {
    UserRole role = filter.getRoles().get(0);
    System.out.println("Append roles");
    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.join("roles").get("roleName"), role.getRoleName()));
        }
```